# R - Como calcular a variação de preço de um período para o outro?

Tags: r, matemática, helper, diff, rowsorter

Olá, gostaria de saber como calcular a variação de preços de um período para o outro. Exemplo:

> Ano | Preço
>
> 2007 | 25
>
> 2008 | 30
>
> 2009 | 7
>
> 2010 | 15

... |...|...

A nova coluna ficaria:

> Ano | Preço | Variação
>
> 2007 | 25 | 25-0 = 25
>
> 2008 | 30 | 30-25 = 5
>
> 2009 | 7 | 7-30 = -23
>
> 2010 | 15 | 15-7 = 8
>
> ... |... |...|...

Não tenho ideia de como fazer isso.
Obrigado desde já !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode usar a função `diff()`:

```
#dados
df <- data.frame(Ano = c(2007,2008,2009,2010), Preço = c(25,30,7,15))

diff(df$Preço)
# [1]   5 -23   8
```

A função `diff()` ignora o primeiro elemento. Para obter o resulto do seu exemplo, podemos usar a função `append()` para adicionar o primeiro elemento:

```
df$Variação <- append(df$Preço[1], diff(df$Preço))

df
#    Ano Preço Variação
# 1 2007    25       25
# 2 2008    30        5
# 3 2009     7      -23
# 4 2010    15        8
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta ! Mas esqueci de por uma parte do problema. 


Empresa | Ano | Preço | Variação

1              |2007 | 25 | 25-0 = 25

1              | 2008 | 30 | 30-25 = 5

1             |2009 | 7 | 7-30 = -23

1              |2010 | 15 | 15-7 = 8

2              |2007 | 20 | 20-0 = 20

2              | 2008 | 27 | 27-20 = 7

2            |2009 | 7 | 7-27 = -20

2              |2010 | 20 | 20-7 = 13

... |... |...|...

São várias empresas. Esse comando resolveria também ??